# ExactTarget - Automation - SOAP API deserialization

Tags: soap, fuel-sdk, c#, automationstudio

When using the C# library and SOAP to retrieve an automation, the `AutomationTasks` property will always be null even though the SOAP envelop of the response actually contains the `AutomationTasks` Node.

Here is the code used to make the SOAP call:

```
RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest(); rr.ObjectType = "Automation";

rr.Filter = new SimpleFilterPart()
{
    Property = "Name",
    SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals,
    Value = new string[] { "automation name" } };

rr.Properties = new string[] { "*" };

status = soapclient.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out results);
```

The SOAP envelop of the response will contain something like this:

```
<AutomationTasks>
    <AutomationTask>
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Activities>
            <Activity>
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                <CreatedDate>2016-02-15T09:25:10.48</CreatedDate>
                <ObjectID>2842d36d-0aa5-4e75-bf14-3f20e7afde3c</ObjectID>
                <CustomerKey>08ffc405-5457-4598-bcb2-877ee3af9c5d</CustomerKey>
                <Name>The name of my query</Name>
                <Description/>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <Definition>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <CustomerKey>08ffc405-5457-4598-bcb2-877ee3af9c5d</CustomerKey>
                </Definition>
                <Sequence>0</Sequence>
            </Activity>
        </Activities>
    </AutomationTask>
</AutomationTasks>
```

There seems to be a problem with the deserialization process.

Moreover, from the data contained in the response, I do not know how could one deduce the type of the activity (query, email, etc.).

Also, I could only obtain the `AutomationTasks` node when using an "*" in the `RetrieveRequest.Properties` field. I could not make it work by explicitly requesting the `AutomationTasks` field.

EDIT:

After a few tests, I discovered that only the Tasks of the automations I created using the API were in the SOAP envelop. In other words, if an automation was created using the marketing cloud application, the AutomationTasks node was empty.